# JavaScript: Comparing the current value to the previous value drawn from Json

Tags: javascript, json

I was not sure how to write the question title or what is the correct way to ask for this question.

The goal is, I am currently drawing data from an external Json file that have about 700 or more data. What I want to do is, when looping through these data, for example, data 1, data 2, data 3...so on, I want the current value to be compared to the previous value and if it is greater, lesser, or equal to, then do something

right now, my code is written like this

```
function myJson() {

    $.getJSON('JsonData.json', function (response) {

        setInterval(function () {
            var TrialCount = response.length;
            updateTrack(X_Data);

            var counter = 0;
            var Info = response[counter];
            var X_Data = Info.X_Json;

            X_Data = X_Data.toFixed(2); // rounds to 2 decimal places

            document.getElementById("DisplayX").innerHTML = X_Data

            counter++;
        }, 500);
    });
};

function updateTrack(X_Data) {
    $('#X').html(X_Data);
        if (current X_Data < previous value){
            document.getElementById("X_Data_img").src = "first image";
        }
        else if (current X_Data > previous value) {
            document.getElementById("X_Data_img").src = "second image";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("X_Data_img").src = "third image";
        }
    };
```

How to put the current X_Data (current'th loop of Json data) to be compared from the previous X_data  (previous'th loop of Json data) ? |

Format of the Json data I have

```
var X_Json= {
  "data1" : "#",
  "data2" : "#",
  "data3" : "#",
   ..
},
{
  "data1" : "#",
  "data2" : "#",
  "data3" : "#",
   ..
},
{
  "data1" : "#",
  "data2" : "#",
  "data3" : "#",
   ..
},
{
  "data1" : "#",
  "data2" : "#",
  "data3" : "#",
   ..
}
```

Comment: Are you thinking that your `setInterval` will somehow magically request another set of JSON data? It won't. Also, don't mix jQuery and native DOM methods; you'll confuse yourself.

Comment: Your `if` and `else if` conditions are the same, the `else if` condition will never be reached. You also set `X_Data` after you call it in `updateTrack()` within `setInterval()`. Not sure if that's correct.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON array. It seems you have an array of objects, with each object having a distinct number of properties.

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj Ah, I see. does this mean that it cannot be used in the function (answer) commented below?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `var previous_value` outside the scope of `updateTrack()` and set the value of it at the end of `updateTrack()` with the current `X_Data` value.

```
var X_Data = [14,22,53,24,6,6,97];

var previous_value = null;

for (var i = 0; i < X_Data.length; i++) {
  var current_value = X_Data[i];
  if (i > 0) { // some sort of first item check
    if (current_value < previous_value) {
      // set first image
    } else if (current_value > previous_value) {
      // set second image
    } else {
      // set third image
    }    
  }
  previous_value = current_value;
}
```

The loop is just to show you how it would work, imagine each iteration of the loop as a separate function call to `updateTrack()`.

This a general pattern for handling in-array comparisons and hopefully will assist you in reaching your answer.

To help you in the right direction for your code, what you want to do is set `counter` outside the function and compare `response[counter].X_Json` to `response[counter - 1].X_Json` and set the image that way and skip it if the `counter` is 0. The way you set `counter` it is being reset each time the function is called.

Comment: I am trying both method and replaced the // set first image, etc to document.getElementById("X_img").src = "img/X.png"; but it does not change up the image..

Comment: @axchink I've made some updates to my question. Feel free to re-read and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm writing them in sublime text and running it through the localhost

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your JSON looks someething like this.

```
var myJson = {
  "data1" : "2",
  "data2" : "5",
  "data3" : "43",
   ..
}
```

If you want to loop through all the properties of an object as if it was an array, then put all the property names inside an array as strings.

```
var myProperties = Object.keys(myJson);
```

This will create an array of property names like this

```
["data1", "data2", "data3"....]
```

You can loop through `myProperties` and use the item names to identify properties in your `myJson` object.

```
for(var i = 1; i < myProperties.length ; i++) {
   if(myJson[myProperties[i]] < myJson[myProperties[i-1]]) {
       //Do something
   } else if(myJson[myProperties[i]] > myJson[myProperties[i-1]]){
      //Do another thing
   } else {
      //Do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: would I declare var myProperties outside of the function? so, top of the source page? or inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Depending your scene, comparing variables in js loops may be accomplished with [html5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Here a small example

```
...inside a loop
if ( $('#somehtmlelement').attr('data-value') !=  getValue() ) {
  console.log("not the same");    
}

$('#somehtmlelement').data('value',getIndex()).attr('data-value',getValue());        
... loop continues
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe I am misunderstanding but are just trying to loop through your json data and compare the current to previous?

```
 $.getJSON('myurl', function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                   if (i > 0 && item.myval < data[i - 1].myval){
                     // do whatever
                    }
                 });              
            });
```

Comment: you have no loop in your example though @axchink

Comment: $.each is the loop   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/    https://api.jquery.com/each/